# Unable to import UTF-8 .txt file into MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql, utf-8, mysql-workbench

I have a **.txt** file in **UTF-8** format with information I am trying to import in an already created table that has rows already in it.

The information in the .txt file is structured like this: (the quotes **are** included in the .txt file)

**"Bob,Smith,25,California,,,,Single,"**

**"John,Doe,72,Nevada,,2,1,Married,"**

**"Will,Smith,22,Texas,1000005,2,1,Married,"**

The query I'm using is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.txt' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

What happens is that all of these records get inserted but get inserted like this

**Bob,null,null,null,null,null,null,null**

**John,null,null,null,null,null,null,null**

**Will,null,null,null,null,null,null,null**

It's like the  **"** is not being caught at the end or something weird . Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the example data provided your fields are not enclosed by quotes but rather the whole record is.

You can use the STARTING BY option to ignore the initial quote and the trailing one should be ignore automatically.

I think what you need is this:

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'your_file.txt' INTO TABLE your_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES STARTING BY '"' TERMINATED BY '\n';

Answer (score 1):

The format of your text file does not make any sense.  (Strangely enough, the way the importer handles it does not make any sense either.  But we have no control over the importer, so let us ignore that.)

The double quotes must surround each field, not each line.  The `ENCLOSED BY '"'` clause refers to the fields, not to the lines.  So, you are telling the importer that your fields are enclosed in quotes, but you are enclosing your lines in quotes.  So, the importer considers each one of your lines as a field.

(Then, the importer proceeds to further chop up your lines at the comma, which makes no sense because the commas are within the quotes, so it should be ignoring them, so the importer is kind of brain-damaged too.)

Comment: No, you are not an idiot.  Mistakes happen even to the best of us.  And the importer could have done a much better job at telling you what you did wrong.  But it did not, because it is brain-damaged.

Answer (score 1):

By using the FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' statement the input file should enclose EACH field data by a " therefor the input file should be as follows

```
"Bob","Smith","25","California","","","","Single",
"John","Doe","72","Nevada","","2","1","Married",
"Will","Smith","22","Texas","1000005","2","1","Married",
```

That should add the data into the fields

Comment: Also on the MySQL workbench there is an import CSV option which maybe an easier option to use...

Comment: How can I write my query such that it will deal with the way the information is stored in my .txt file as of now? I only ask that because this text file is not really holding 3 records, its holding 500,000

Comment: Or should I get rid of the fields enclosed line since I have fields terminated by the ","

Comment: Personally I would do a search and replace on a copy of your datafile removing the " and then use the import CSV option see how that goes.... I've always had more luck with that than the load data command.

Failing that try the following command

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.txt' INTO TABLE mytable TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'